# PrintJob implementation using linked-list based queue

Tags: java, printing, linked-list, queue, implementation

I have a school project that requires me to create a Printer class which represent the printer that will receive and process Print Jobs.

Everything else seems to work fine, but my `process()` method doesn't seem to work correctly. It processes and removes the requested print job but it doesn't seem to stop processing print job when `size() == 0`(each tray is originally set to hold 100 pages).

It is not supposed to print out anything when there is no paper or `size() == 0` and put that unprocessed job back to the end of the queue. Please tell me what did I do wrong here. Your help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

**Printer.Java. process() method**

```
        public Printer() {
            white = new PaperTray("White", "white", 100);
            yellow = new PaperTray("Yellow", "yellow", 100);
            printJobQ = new LinkedUnbndQueue<PrintJob>();
        }  
        //...
        /*
         * if the tray is empty then the job will not be processed
         * and will be added back to the end of the queue.
         */     
        public PrintJob process() {
            PrintJob currentJob = new PrintJob();
                try {
                   // make a reference to the dequeue job
                    currentJob = printJobQ.dequeue();

                   // remove the number of pages used for printing 
                   // from the appropriate tray                                                
                    if((currentJob.getColor().equalsIgnoreCase("white")) && (white.size() != 0)) {
                        white.remove(currentJob.getNumberOfPage());
                    } else if((currentJob.getColor().equalsIgnoreCase("yellow")) && (yellow.size() != 0)) {
                        yellow.remove(currentJob.getNumberOfPage());

                    // add unprocessed print job back to the queue***
                    } else if((white.size() == 0) || (yellow.size() == 0)) { 
                        printJobQ.enqueue(currentJob);
                    }

                } catch (QueueUnderFlowException e) {
                 //...
                } catch (PaperUnderFlowException e) {
                 //...
                }
            // return the info of the processed print job
            return currentJob;
        }
```

**PaperTray.java**

```
    // private int numberOfPage;    
    //...  
    public int size() {
        if(numberOfPage <= 0) {
            return 0;
        } else if(numberOfPage >= 100) {
            return 100;
        } else {
            return numberOfPage;
        }
    }
    //remove paper when print
    public void remove(int paper) throws PaperUnderFlowException {
        numberOfPage = numberOfPage - paper;
        if(numberOfPage < 0) {
            throw new PaperUnderFlowException("Paper under flow. Tray is empty");
        }
    }
```

**LinkedUnbndQueue.java**

```
    // private LLNode front, rear;
    //...
    public T dequeue() throws QueueUnderFlowException {
        if(isEmpty()) {
            throw new QueueUnderFlowException("Dequeue attempted on an empty queue");
        }
        else {
            T elementToRemove = front.getInfo();
            front = front.getLink();
            if(front == null)
                rear = null;

            return elementToRemove;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a couple of quick housekeeping things. Make sure you aren't just posting your homework problems on this site. We aren't here to do your work.

Second make sure you aren't just posting all of your code. Only post what is relevant and add information as necessary later on. We can't read through all of your code and debug it for you.

Finally answering your question.

```
T elementToRemove = front.getInfo();
        front = front.getLink();
        if(front == null)
            rear = null;

        return elementToRemove;
    }

}
```

This section doesn't seem to be actually dequeueing anything. You never take the element out. You just return an element that is the front.

Disclaimer: this was just after a cursory look at your code so take some time to make sure that your linked list is actually being manipulated properly.

Comment: It does dequeue the front element. I just make the reference to the information of the front element and return that information (as part of my project's requirement). The actually front element was removed from the queue `front = front.getLink();` . But that is not my question. My process() method did dequeue the print job. The problem is, it doesn't seem to stop processing print job when the tray is empty and doesn't put that job back to the end of the queue. And thanks for the advice, I took off part of my codes. Hopefully, it's clearer.

Comment: Yes it looks a lot clearer thanks! Try adding a `return` in your `else if` statement where you `enqueue(currentJob)`. This should end the process method as soon as it realizes there are not enough pages.

Comment: Have you tried adding a print statement to see that the `else if` is actually executed successfully. Also you could add print statements to your process method in other places to monitor the paper level.

Comment: Oh nvm. looks like you figured it out!

Answer (score 0):

I think I figure it out. Instead of

```
 else if((white.size() == 0) || (yellow.size() == 0)) { 
                        printJobQ.enqueue(currentJob);
                    }
```

It should be

```
   if((currentJob.getColor().equalsIgnoreCase("white")) && (white.size() != 0)) {
        if((white.size() - currentJob.getNumberOfPage()) <= 0)
                printJobQ.enqueue(currentJob);
        white.remove(currentJob.getNumberOfPage());
```